# flex column in parent flex column with height set to 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having an issue with flex column, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to create a modal with a header, body, and footer, which is already set in a flex column - which allows the body to allocate 100% of the height unused in the modal.

Inside the body of the modal, I would like to add another flex column with two additional divs, one for a search box and another for scrollable content.

I am aware we can move the search bar into the header, but the whole idea is to have the body of the modal dynamic, to allow different types of content (other/multiple input controls).

However, the issue comes in when trying to add a flex column inside an existing flex column with a 100% height, it does not seem to abide by the rules. I have added a very basic JSFiddle to issutrate the issue at hand. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/zsgqc34o/1/

```css
    .flex-col {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .h-100 {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .modal {
      height: 400px;
      background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
    }
    
    .body {
      background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200);
    }
    
    .content-body {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="modal flex-col" style="padding-right: 40px;"> <!-- added padding to see parent height/size -->
    
       <div class="header">
         <h1>
           Modal Header
         </h1>
       </div>
    
       <div class="body h-100 flex-col">
    
         <div class="content-header">
           <input placeholder="search" />
         </div>
         <div class="content-body h-100">
           <ul>
             <li>a</li>
             <li>b</li>
             <li>c</li>
             <li>d</li>
             <li>e</li>
             <li>f</li>
             <li>g</li>
             <li>h</li>
             <li>i</li>
             <li>j</li>
             <li>k</li>
             <li>l</li>
             <li>m</li>
             <li>n</li>
             <li>o</li>
             <li>p</li>
             <li>q</li>
             <li>r</li>
             <li>s</li>
             <li>t</li>
             <li>u</li>
             <li>v</li>
             <li>w</li>
             <li>x</li>
             <li>y</li>
             <li>z</li>
           </ul>
         </div>
    
       </div>
    
       <div class="footer">
         <button>
           close
         </button>
       </div>
    
     </div>
```

Comment: Problem not entirely clear. The fiddle seems to be doing what you want (in Chrome). Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to increase the height dynamically

```
.h-100 {
   height: 100%;
 }
.modal {
   min-height:400px
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body > .modal{
  height: 100%;
}
```